# Right mouse click and selecting the appropriate item using Playwright

Tags: playwright, playwright-python

Once the page loads, Is there a way to select the option from right click

**Example**: I am using locator and able to perform right click

await page.getByRole("document").click( { button: "right" });
Now I would like to click on "View Page Source" . Is there an option to do this using Playwright

Basically, the use case is to automate. I expect a different item in the right click which will be useful in automating.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is not supported by Playwright. Seems like a similar issue like this https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-python/issues/676.

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on what you're trying to accomplish with the right-click.

**If you're trying to retrieve the source of the page**

You can get it with `page.content()` easily, or you can use `CDPSession` to access Chrome's `page.captureSnapshot`

**If you're trying to right-click a custom context menu which is coded in your app**

Playwright doesn't support selecting options from *Chrome's* context menu, but when you say "I expect a different item," this tells me that your application may have a right-click handler which opens its own in-app context menu instead of Chrome's.  In that case, you can locate and left-click on the element that is now visible as a result of your right-click.

Something like

```
await page.locator(".right-clickable-element").click( { button: "right" });
await page.locator(".app-custom-context-menu-option").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

For Java :

```
   Locator button = page.locator("button_xpath");
   button.click(new Locator.ClickOptions().setButton(MouseButton.RIGHT));
```